# Oracle connection not open

Tags: asp.net, oracle, ado.net

I have written a code in ASP.NET to fetch data from Oracle.But when I upload it on server machine it's connection not open.

Connection String is:-

```
<add providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" 
     name="ca_eFormsVSED" 
     connectionString="DATA SOURCE=192.168.0.11:1521/xe;USER ID=TESTUSER;Password=*****;"/>
```

This connection string successfully work at local machine, but not on server machine.
Please suggest how to make it work.

Comment: "Does not work" is by far the [most useless error description](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html) ever.

Comment: is server on the same subnet? e.i., from the server what happens if you ping 192.168.0.11? Seriously - how are we supposed to diagnose a connection problem without even a real error message to go on?

Comment: if database is located on the same server, try to change your Data Source to xe (instead of 192.168.0.11:1521/xe)

Comment: yaa 192.108.0.11 ping sucessfully @michael Broughton